# Need random unique code using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I'd created a Google form for collecting data from users. In this form I'm going to ask the site name and want to replace it with Unique code.

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1JTStfAZGFBAFjVxgH0aZlMUroVsBijC0sfOvuXvqce8/viewform?usp=send_form#start=invite

I'd written the codes with google apps script for this which is given below but every time it generate new unique code and also replace previous one also.

```
function SendConfirmationMail(e) {
  try {
    var ss, bcc, sendername, subject, columns, username;
    var message, value, textbody, usermail, track, code;

    // This is your email address and you will be in the BCC
    bcc = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

    // This will show up as the sender's name
    sendername = "Support Team";

    // This is the submitter's Name
    username = e.values[1];

    // This is the submitter's email address
    usermail = e.values[2];

    // Custom subject for Google Docs emails
    subject = "Support Ticket";

    // Random Code for Google Docs emails
    ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    track = new Array();
    var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var string_length = 10;
    var lastRow = ss.getLastRow()-1;
    var randomstring = '';
    for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
      var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
      randomstring += chars.substring(rnum, rnum+1);
    }
    track.push(randomstring);

    code = ss.getRange(2, 5, lastRow, 1).setValue(track);

    // This is the body of the auto-reply
    message = "Hi <b>" +username+ " !!!</b> <br><br> Your message has been successfully received.<br>";


    GmailApp.sendEmail(usermail, subject, messag, 
                       {bcc: bcc, name: sendername, htmlBody: message});

    } catch (e) {
        Logger.log(e.toString());
    }

}
```

But I want to generate unique code for every submission. Please update me.

Answer (score 1):

I've struggled with this sort of thing before, and the complexity depends on the security it needs (as far as I can tell, this is all internal, so not much).

I'm not sure I understand why you'd put your unique code as an editable text box (I'm assuming site name is just a holdover and you would eventually either make it a non-editable `div` or not show it at all).

Either way, one method is to keep an array of all your previous unique codes in [properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties), although if this is used a lot, then that could be too much (look at the [quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas?hl=fr), which [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4kb) says is about 500 words conservatively).

So, maybe you could have a few scriptDBs (or even a spreadsheet, although it's slower) that you combine to get a final array of all your previous codes. Your `randomstring` algorithm could be fine (as long as you check to make sure it doesn't exist in the overarching scriptDB array).

Look at [Generate random string/characters in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349404/generate-a-string-of-5-random-characters-in-javascript) for other random string ideas, but just make sure (again, if this gets very popular) that there are enough new possibilities.

You don't want this hanging while looking for a new code, so I would also add a counter and do something else if it takes more than 100 iterations (if this is all internal, it might not be a bad idea to have a 5-10 character code just to keep the chances of it not finding a new string quickly much lower).